# how to make textArea scrollable in nokia asha sdk1.0

Tags: java, java-me, nokia, s40

i am working on nokia asha sdk1.0 .i am using TextArea in my app but my textarea not scrollable.i used following code so how to make it scrollable.

```
Display.init(this);
        Display.getInstance().setForceFullScreen(true);
        Form form=new Form();
        form.setScrollable(false);
        form.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(10175989);
        form.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Container northcon=new Container();
        int northcomponentHT=form.getPreferredH()*20/100;
        northcon.setPreferredH(northcomponentHT);
        Label northlab=new Label("NORTH");
        northcon.addComponent(northlab);
        form.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH,northcon);
        Container centercon=new Container();
        TextArea textarea=new TextArea();
        int centercomponentHT=form.getPreferredH()*60/100;
        textarea.setPreferredH(centercomponentHT);
        textarea.setPreferredW(form.getPreferredW());
        String string=new String("dfjjkfjknfsdfhkfjfjcannot be surpassed by that of watching electric lights. Everyone in Gods creation is special and so are wcannot be surpassed by that of watching electric lights. Everyone in Gods creation is special and so are wcannot be surpassed by that of watching electric lights. Everyone in Gods creation is special and so are wcannot be surpassed by that of watching electric lights. Everyone in Gods creation is special and so are wcannot be surpassed by that of watching electric lights. Everyone in Gods creation is special and so are wcannot be surpassed by that of watching electric lights. Everyone in Gods creation is special and so are wcannot be surpassed by that of watching electric lights. Everyone in Gods creation is special and so are wkfiufjkfjkfjfjkfjierojfkjjiojkldf;jasf;ljsf;jl;dfjas;dflk;lfj;asdfljsdl;fkjierojeiorjoiejkfjoeirjjeoirjoejo;efdfkljoijerjorj");
        textarea.setScrollVisible(true);

        textarea.setText(string);
        textarea.setEditable(false);
        textarea.setGrowByContent(true);
        textarea.setRows(50);

        //centercon.setScrollable(true);
        centercon.addComponent(textarea);

        form.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER,centercon);
        Container southcon=new Container();
        int southcomponentHT=form.getPreferredH()*20/100;
        southcon.setPreferredH(southcomponentHT);
        Label southlab=new Label("SOUTH");
        southcon.addComponent(southlab);
        form.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH,southcon);
        form.show();
```

Comment: Do you use the LWUIT library? Then you should add the LWUIT tag.

Comment: I think this link can help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144349/lwuit-textarea-scroll-issue

Answer (score 1):

To make TextArea text scrollable, you must use a Scroll Pane.

You would need to do something like

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textarea);
```

See more on JScrollPanes at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html

Comment: My platform is javaME .We can't use any component of swing in my platform as i think.so give me any other way to make scrollable the textArea

Comment: anyone please give me specific answer to my question.i got stuck